# Determine if $\int_2^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x\ln x}dx$ is convergent or not

Tags: calculus, integration

**Problem:**

Determine if $\int_2^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x\ln x}dx$ converges or diverges.

---

**What I tried:**

I tried to IBP first, but it has $\sin x\ln(\ln x)$ so if $x\to \infty$, $\sin x\ln(\ln x)\to\infty$ so I thought $\int_2^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x\ln x}dx = \infty$ but WA and my book says that it converges.

Did I make a mistake? Or is my book wrong?

Comment: What is the full form of IBP ?

Comment: Have a look at https://mathsci.kaist.ac.kr/~kdryul/files/articles/Dirichlet's%20Test%20for%20Improper%20Integrals.pdf

Comment: How did you get $\sin x \ln \ln x \to \infty$? It is $0$ at integer multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: Why not compare it with $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \ dx$?

Comment: @TobyMak It could be problematic because we do not have absolute convergence for these integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x) =\frac{1}{x\ln x}$ is monotonically decreasing and tends to $0$ at infinity. The function $g(x)=\sin x$ ha the property that $$\left|\int_2^{A} g(x)dx \right|\leq 100$$ for all $A>2.$ Hence the integral $$\int_2^{\infty} f(x) g(x) dx$$ converges by Dirichlet criterion.

Comment: Just curious, why $100$? $2$ would do just as well.